# Hibernate is randomly generating joda time columns in my database as tiny blobs

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I have a bit a of an odd situation happening and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a set of Hibernate annotated entity classes that have Jodatime date time fields on them. When hibernate generates my schema some of the date time fields are set up correctly as DateTime columns in MySQL and others are created as tiny blobs. I am using the Usertype library to do my type mapping for me but I have tried it with the joda-time-hibernate library and I get the same result. The weird thing is that these columns are all identical in the way they are being declared in my code e.g.

This one generates a tiny blob instead of a date time:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime respondedTime;
```

But this one in a different class generates a date time column correctly:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime date;
```

So I was wondering if anybody has experienced something similar happen to them or if they know how to ensure that Hibernate generates DateTime columns for my datetime fields.

If it makes any difference I am using usertype version 1.8 and jodatime version 1.6 with hibernate 3.6.0.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jthalbom mentioned in the comments this turned out to be a classpath issue. I cleaned up the jars that were loaded onto my classpath and voila, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens if Hibernate can't find the user type for a column *or* when the `UserType` implementation thinks it can't handle the type.

So either there is a type on the parameter or there is a bug in the `UserType` or `DateTime` is a different type in the two places.

To avoid typos, I suggest to use `@TypeDefs` to create more readable names for user types.

See [this blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types).

Comment: Ok. So I ran through all of my imports and my type strings to make sure I was working with jodatime DateTime objects and that the correct UserType was being specified on all my dates and it still comes through as a tinyblob.

Comment: @Michael - but, did you check the classpath at the time when hibernate is generating the schema.  that is likely where the problem lies.

Comment: The problem looks like it may have been a classpath issue as I did a bit of refactoring and made all of my entities inherit from a mapped super class and it looks like the issue was resolved as a result. I will do a bit more digging to see what really happened. But I think you were correct on the class path issue.